# Don't understand Template implementation of the JLospinoso books

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

In the JLospinoso (c++ Crash Course), chapter 10 about unit testing.[Link to the book page](https://books.google.fr/books?id=m0RBDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT438&lpg=PT438&dq=Writing%20a%20Skeleton%20AutoBrake%20Class%20Before%20you%20can%20write%20tests,%20you%20need%20to%20write%20a%20skeleton%20class,%20which%20implements%20an%20interface%20but%20provides%20no%20functionality.%20It%E2%80%99s%20useful%20in%20TDD%20because%20you%20can%E2%80%99t%20compile%20a%20test%20without%20a%20shell%20of%20the%20class%20you%E2%80%99re%20testing.&source=bl&ots=GXqtIfcYFx&sig=ACfU3U3hsePWgnRM3Zs8NfVZp2BYpyC9kw&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjh19754ZzqAhWmxYUKHXgbD6AQ6AEwAHoECAwQAQ#v=onepage&q=Writing%20a%20Skeleton%20AutoBrake%20Class%20Before%20you%20can%20write%20tests%2C%20you%20need%20to%20write%20a%20skeleton%20class%2C%20which%20implements%20an%20interface%20but%20provides%20no%20functionality.%20It%E2%80%99s%20useful%20in%20TDD%20because%20you%20can%E2%80%99t%20compile%20a%20test%20without%20a%20shell%20of%20the%20class%20you%E2%80%99re%20testing.&f=false)

There is this code (simplified)

```
struct BrakeCommand {
    double time_to_collision_s;
};

template<typename T>
struct AutoBrake {
    AutoBrake(const T& publish) : publish{publish} {}

---snips---

private:
    const T& publish;
}
```

Which is called

```
AutoBrake auto_brake{[](const BrakeCommand&) {}};
```

1 - I absolutely don't understand why there is this much {} [] ?? And nothing about the template...

2 - C++ compiler MSVC raise this error

> "error C2955: 'AutoBrake': use of class template requires template
> argument list"

Why is there a template here ? How to compile this program ?

Thanks a lot,

Comment: 1. `[](const BrakeCommand&) {}` is a so-called *lambda expression*. 2. This code requires C++17 to compile, make sure your compiler is new enough, and C++17 features are enabled in the settings.

Comment: Thanks a lot to help a beginner like me, it works ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

{}[] symbols which are confused you it's a part of the [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) definition passed by [initializer_list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) to AutoBrake constructor.

Let's go through the code line step by step

> AutoBrake auto_brake{[](const BrakeCommand&) {}};

1 Lambda which takes BrakeCommand as an argument and does nothing

```
[](const BrakeCommand&) {};
```

2 The constructor with initialized_list, lambda as an argument for it

```
auto variable = [](const BrakeCommand&) {}; // to simplify understanding what is going on further
AutoBrake auto_brake{variable}; // it might be replaced by AutoBrake auto_brake(variable);
```

Now let's figure out how the template works.

```
AutoBrake auto_brake{[](const BrakeCommand&) {}};
```

By this was declared that the template parameter T, for your instance is a function.

So code generated by preprocessor from your template will look as

```
template<std::function>
struct AutoBrake {
    AutoBrake(const std::function& publish) : publish{publish} {}

---snips---

private:
    const std::function& publish;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
```

And everything works fine !